# Show/Hide Rows in React (Tricky concept)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a tricky situation and I am unable to wrap around it and bring a workaround. Any technical advice is appreciated.

**Here's an example.**

I have a table and I show some **tasks** in each row. Some of the rows might have additional **subtasks**. There is a last column on the table with icons to expand and collapse for the subtasks,

When user toggles on the arrow button at subtask, it will either expand or collapse that subtask. So the user can individually click on arrow for each subtask row and the below subtasks will show or hide based on the toggle. I hope it makes sense in explaining this.

Now, I want to use a expand/collapse icon at the header level. If user toggles using the icon on header level, all subtasks are collapsed/expanded at once.

How can I ensure that a user can expand/collapse at header level and also at subtasks level at the same time. Because in my situation, if I collapse header level, I cannot expand subtask level individually because it has a flag which points to header level icon.

i.e. if `headerIcon` is `false`, subtask level is set false too. Now when subtask level is false, if I try to click on subtask level and expand that particular subtask, it wont allow me because the headerIcon is still false.

How do I ensure that I can expand/collapse both at header level and subtask level at same time. Please let me know if its not clear, I will try to make it clearer by editing this question.

Comment: How about track the Header Icon state and the subIcons' state seperately. That way each one is independent of the other? Note: It would be helpful if you added a simple illustration of what you are trying to accomplish. Like a low level wireframe or something.

Comment: You've done a decent job of explaining the problem but without a [mcve] it also makes it tricky for people to provide solutions, especially having to code them from scratch

Comment: You could also track all the states for the individual rows in the parent component. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-l52tbr?file=index.tsx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR:** Have a CSS togglable class on the `SubTask`, and pass down the parent `TaskItem` state to the subtask, [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to update child state with parent updates.

[Live Cond Sandbox here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-task-toggler-94zj9?file=/src/Tasks.js:1240-1899)

Breakdown...

---

Here, is another approach. I like to separate the state from the data. Much as react is fast with its reconciliation, I prefer updating the DOM structure for updates that only touch the **layout**, via CSS. That way I can use an additional class on the container element that hides and shows the children instead of re-rendering the entire tree conditionally. More so if the updates not touching the underlying data logic, I opt for css control in that case.

Based on your statement/question, `How can I ensure that a user can expand/collapse at header level and also at subtasks level at the same time.`, I assumed that for this to be achievable, you can never collapsed the task completely without showing a list of the subtasks, I structured the task layout approached.

> Assume the following component tree structure

```
Tasks (ul.tasks-list)
│
└───header (li.heading)
│
└───TaskItem 1 (li.task) // -> .task-collapsed
│ └───task-summary (div.task-main)
│ │ │ - Title
│ │ │ - Assignee
│ │ └ - Expand Icon Action (onClick parent)
│ │
│ └───SubTasks (ul.subtasks-list)
│ └─── SubTaskItem 1 (li.subtask) // -> .subtask-collapsed
│ └───subtask-summary (div.subtask-summary)
│ │ │ - Title
│ │ │ - Summary
│ │ └ - Expand Icon Action (onClick subtask)
│ │
│ └───subtask-body (div.subtask-body) // Targeted by CSS.
```

1. That said, have the individual sub tasks control their own visibility state by toggling a class(`.subtask-collapsed`) on their container(`.subtask`) on clicking the down arrow. Have a CSS style that targets the `subtask body` and hides the details. Set the initial state from the parent `collapsed` state.

```
&.subtask {
  &.subtask-collapsed {
    .subtask-summary {
      .arrow-icon {
        transform: rotate(0deg);
        transition: transform 0.2s ease-out;
      }
    }

    .subtask-body {
      display: none;
    }
  }
}
```

2. Since the parent has control over multiple children and has powers to override the state of the children, have the children keep tabs on the parent state. If the parent's state changes, force the children to update too.

```js
const SubTaskItem = ({
  title,
  summary,
  status,
  descripiton,
  parentExpanded
}) => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(parentExpanded);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsExpanded(() => !isExpanded);
  };

  // Note :: This is important to force re-rendering of child when parent updates prop.
  useEffect(() => {
    setIsExpanded(() => parentExpanded);
  }, [parentExpanded]);

  return (
    <li className={`subtask ${!isExpanded ? "subtask-collapsed" : ""}`}>
      <div className="subtask-summary">
        <div className="col">{title}</div>
        <div className="col">{summary}</div>
        <div className="col" onClick={handleClick}>
          <Arrow />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div className="subtask-body">
        <h3>Title: {title}</h3>
        <h4>Summary: {summary}</h4>
        <h4>Status: {status}</h4>
        <p>{descripiton}</p>
      </div>
    </li>
  );
};
```

3. We could control the parent CSS classes and have children sub tasks classes have their styles overriden by `important`, but that gets ugly very fast. Instead, for this case we pass down the parent state as a prop.

```js
const TaskItem = ({ title, assigned, subTasks }) => {
  const [isExpanded, setIsExpanded] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setIsExpanded(() => !isExpanded);
  };

  return (
    <li className={`task ${!isExpanded ? "task-collapsed" : ""}`}>
      <div className="task-main">
        <div className="col">{title}</div>
        <div className="col">{assigned}</div>
        <div className="col task-action" onClick={handleClick}>
          <Arrow />
        </div>
      </div>
      {/* Parent Task passes down status to force subtasks to update */}
      <SubTasks parentExpanded={isExpanded} subtaskItems={subTasks} />
    </li>
  );
};
```

Note:

- Sometimes updates to the prop does not force the children to re-render. Have `useEffect` hook that forces the child to re-compute its state if the parent state `parentExpanded` changes.
- PS, User experience-wise, I hope you have an action button that collapses the subtasks completely so you can only see a minimal task lists

Here is the [link to the CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-answer-task-toggler-94zj9?file=/src/Tasks.js:944-958) that has the working Demo.

Comment: Dude, that is insance. With providing 3 different solutions with a working example.

Comment: I am glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways on how to do it, but I would do it in the following way. First, let's define your data structure. Let's say it's an array of task objects. Every object has a `name` property of your task and an array of subtask objects `subtasks`. Every subtask object contains a name of the subtask and a property `hidden`, when it's true, the subtask is visible and when it's false, it's hidden/collapsed.

To illustrate:

```js
  state = {
    tasks: [{
        name: "Task 1",
        subtasks: [{
          name: "Subtask 1A",
          hidden: false
        }, {
          name: "Subtask 1B",
          hidden: false
        }]
      },
      {
        name: "Task 2",
        subtasks: [{
          name: "Subtask 2A",
          hidden: false
        }, {
          name: "Subtask 2B",
          hidden: false
        }]
      }
    ]
  };
```

Notice that we do not have the header level `hidden` property or any 'flag' of any sort that indicates that a header is collapsed or not. It's just easier to manage state without it.

So how do you do it then?

1. To collapse or show any subtask, you change the value of `hidden` to true or false.
2. To collapse or show all subtasks of a task, you cycle through all its children subtasks and change their `hidden` properties to true or false.

In other words, you keep the state of a task in its subtasks, so you have 3 states that are not directly set on a task but depend on the state of its subtasks:

1. All subtasks' `hidden` properties are `true` means that the whole
   task is collapsed
2. All subtasks' `hidden` properties are `false`
   means that the whole task is shown
3. If some of the subtasks are
   hidden and some are not, you are in a mixed state.

In the same way you can implement a button to collapse/show all the subtasks of all tasks, but the function behind it instead of changing the status of all subtasks of a particular task, you cycle through all the subtasks of all the tasks.

Comment: i got the gist of it. thanks for explaining it well. cheers